Fix Nested set values (left, right) based on parent_id or path
I'm trying to rebuild nested sets values using a query
The problem is that i'm getting an error
Query 3 ERROR at Line 110: : Can't reopen table: 'tmp_tree'
What seems to be the problem?
My directories table structure is:
id, name, path, parent_id, _lft, _rgt
When trying to execute this query:
Explanation of bellow query:
Procedure Definition and Error Handling:
Drops the existing procedure if it exists.
Changes the delimiter to // to allow using ; within the procedure.
Creates the tree_recover procedure.
Declares an exit handler to rollback and resignal on any SQL exception.
Variable Declarations:
Declares variables for storing node IDs, parent IDs, left values, and a starting ID.
Memory Table Setup:
Sets the maximum heap table size.
Starts a new transaction.
Creates a temporary table tmp_tree in MEMORY to perform the calculations efficiently.
Data Initialization:
Inserts data from the original directories table into tmp_tree.
Sets all _lft and _rgt values to NULL to prepare for recalculation.
Root Node Initialization:
Finds root nodes (nodes with parent_id IS NULL) and initializes their _lft and _rgt values.
Index Management:
Drops and recreates indexes on _lft and _rgt columns to optimize performance during range queries.
Node Processing:
Selects an unprocessed node that has a processed parent.
Retrieves the parent ID and left value of the parent node.
Updates _rgt and _lft values of nodes to the right of the current node to make space.
Sets the _lft and _rgt values for the current node.
Final Update and Cleanup:
Updates the original directories table with the calculated _lft and _rgt values.
Commits the transaction.
Drops the temporary table.
-- Drop the existing procedure if it exists to avoid conflicts
DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS tree_recover;

-- Change the delimiter to '//' to allow the use of semicolons within the procedure
DELIMITER //

-- Create the stored procedure tree_recover
CREATE PROCEDURE tree_recover ()
MODIFIES SQL DATA
BEGIN
    -- Declare variables to store the current node's ID, parent ID, left value, and starting ID
    DECLARE currentId CHAR(36);
    DECLARE currentParentId CHAR(36);
    DECLARE currentLeft INT;
    DECLARE startId INT DEFAULT 1;

    -- Declare an exit handler to rollback the transaction in case of an error
    DECLARE EXIT HANDLER FOR SQLEXCEPTION
    BEGIN
        ROLLBACK; -- Rollback the transaction
        RESIGNAL; -- Propagate the exception
    END;

    -- Set the maximum size for MEMORY tables to 512MB to ensure enough space
    SET max_heap_table_size = 1024 * 1024 * 512;

    -- Start a new transaction
    START TRANSACTION;

    -- Drop temporary tables if they exist
    DROP TEMPORARY TABLE IF EXISTS tmp_tree;
    DROP TEMPORARY TABLE IF EXISTS tmp_unprocessed;

    -- Create a temporary table in MEMORY to perform the updates efficiently
    CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE tmp_tree (
        id CHAR(36) NOT NULL, -- Node ID
        parent_id CHAR(36) DEFAULT NULL, -- Parent node ID
        _lft INT UNSIGNED DEFAULT NULL, -- Left value
        _rgt INT UNSIGNED DEFAULT NULL, -- Right value
        PRIMARY KEY (id), -- Primary key on ID
        KEY parent_id_idx (parent_id) -- Index on parent ID for fast lookups
    ) ENGINE = MEMORY;

    -- Insert all nodes from the original directories table into the temporary table
    INSERT INTO tmp_tree (id, parent_id, _lft, _rgt)
    SELECT id, parent_id, _lft, _rgt FROM directories;

    -- Set all left and right values to NULL to prepare for recalculation
    UPDATE tmp_tree SET _lft = NULL, _rgt = NULL;

    -- Create another temporary table to track unprocessed nodes
    CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE tmp_unprocessed (
        id CHAR(36) NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY
    ) ENGINE = MEMORY;

    -- Initialize tmp_unprocessed with all node IDs
    INSERT INTO tmp_unprocessed (id)
    SELECT id FROM tmp_tree;

    -- Initialize left and right values for root nodes (nodes with no parent)
    WHILE EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM tmp_tree WHERE parent_id IS NULL AND _lft IS NULL AND _rgt IS NULL LIMIT 1) DO
        -- Set the left and right values for the next root node
        UPDATE tmp_tree
        SET _lft = startId, _rgt = startId + 1
        WHERE parent_id IS NULL AND _lft IS NULL AND _rgt IS NULL
        LIMIT 1;
        -- Increment the startId by 2 for the next node
        SET startId = startId + 2;
    END WHILE;

    -- Process each node in the temporary table to set the left and right values
    WHILE EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM tmp_unprocessed LIMIT 1) DO
        -- Select an unprocessed node that has a processed parent
        SELECT id INTO currentId
        FROM tmp_unprocessed
        WHERE id IN (SELECT id FROM tmp_tree WHERE _lft IS NULL AND parent_id IS NOT NULL AND parent_id IN (SELECT id FROM tmp_tree WHERE _lft IS NOT NULL))
        LIMIT 1;

        -- Get the parent ID of the current node
        SELECT parent_id INTO currentParentId
        FROM tmp_tree WHERE id = currentId;

        -- Get the left value of the parent node
        SELECT _lft INTO currentLeft
        FROM tmp_tree WHERE id = currentParentId;

        -- Shift the right values of nodes to the right of the current node by 2
        UPDATE tmp_tree SET _rgt = _rgt + 2 WHERE _rgt > currentLeft;

        -- Shift the left values of nodes to the right of the current node by 2
        UPDATE tmp_tree SET _lft = _lft + 2 WHERE _lft > currentLeft;

        -- Set the left and right values for the current node
        UPDATE tmp_tree
        SET _lft = currentLeft + 1, _rgt = currentLeft + 2
        WHERE id = currentId;

        -- Mark the current node as processed by removing it from tmp_unprocessed
        DELETE FROM tmp_unprocessed WHERE id = currentId;
    END WHILE;

    -- Update the original directories table with the calculated left and right values
    UPDATE directories
    JOIN tmp_tree ON directories.id = tmp_tree.id
    SET directories._lft = tmp_tree._lft, directories._rgt = tmp_tree._rgt;

    -- Commit the transaction to make the changes permanent
    COMMIT;

    -- Drop the temporary tables as they are no longer needed
    DROP TEMPORARY TABLE tmp_tree;
    DROP TEMPORARY TABLE tmp_unprocessed;
END//

-- Restore the delimiter to the default ';'
DELIMITER ;

Call tree_recover();

I tried both of the solutions in this question but none of them worked
Can't reopen table: 'lc1' in mysql
I'm running all of this on mysql 8

See https://stackoverflow.com/a/78584624/10138734

This not a duplicated question, I edited the question accordingly

You report that Query 3 ERROR at Line 110: : Can't reopen table: 'tmp_tree'. But there is a problem - this is NOT error message generated by MySQL. What tool produces this error message? And what is Line 110 mentioned in this message? The stored procedure itself consists from 106 rows only...

I'm using TablePlus the problem is can be found here https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.4/en/temporary-table-problems.html#:~:text=The%20Can't%20reopen%20table%20error%20also%20occurs%20if%20you,different%20statements%20within%20the%20function.
But I dont really know how to use this to solve the poblem I have

MySQL produces Error 1137. You provide the tale about this message made by your tool. Execute your code in CLI and obtain original error description. Debug your SP and find the code line which causes your error.
